# For loop should stop when image is not available in the directory - javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

My requirement is that, to showcase images available in the directory to the browser view. Using javascript. For that, i have named all images with a same prefix and changed the number to the each image at the end.as shown below.

Folder
  gal-img-1.jpg
  gal-img-2.jpg
  gal-img-3.jpg
  gal-img-4.jpg
  ...

now the code i written something like below.

```
for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
        var objImg = new Image();
        var imgSrc = '/assets/images/work/gal-img-'+j+'.jpg'
        objImg.src = imgSrc;
        objImg.onerror = function (){
          j = 11; 
          console.log("done")
        }
      }
```

Now, when i check console, i can see the loop is not stopping when there is no image as 'gal-img-5.jpg'. i see 404 not found error for 5,6,7,8,9,10. after these errors i see "done"(console.log).

Here i want is when there is no image in the directory the for loop needs to stop.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: images are loaded asynchronously - you'll need to wait for one image to succeed (onload) before proceeding to try the next

Comment: You can try the `break` statement...

Comment: break stops for the very first loop right. I need for loop to run till images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of recursion using [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)'s mentioned `onload` method.

```
function loadImages(i) {
    objImg = new Image();
    objImg.src = `/assets/images/work/gal-img-${i}.jpg`;

    objImg.onload = function () {
        if (i < 11) loadImages(++i); // Always have an exit condition with recursion
    }
}


// You need to call loadImages(0)
```

The above would show an error message for the file not found and will not try to load more images.